# Javascript Promise resolve confusion

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

```
private runMiddlewares(route: Route | ExceptionRoute, request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            route.middlewares.forEach(async (middleware: IMiddleware) => {
                console.log('begin run middleware');
                await middleware.process(request, response);
                console.log('resolve run middleware');
                console.log(request.body);
            });
            console.log('resolve all runMiddlewares');
            resolve();
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I have written this function `runMiddlewares` which should ideally resolve() when all the `middleware.process()` have resolved. I am using typescript `await` functionality but it doesn't seem to be working.
I expect something like this to happen inside `route.middlewares.forEach(`

- 'begin run middleware'
- then awaits resolves
- 'resolve run middleware'

This continues for all of the middlewares in `forEach` loop and when the list is all done then and only then 'resolve all runMiddlewares' should be printed and finally, `private runMiddlewares( ... )` should resolve.

But instead, `forEach` is now getting immediately resolved thus preventing all of the middlewares to even complete.

How should this be handled? I thought that `await` will take care of it inside the `forEach` loop and only then `resolve` of `runMiddlewares` will be called in the end.
What am I missing here?

Comment: The thing could be you are using an `await` inside a `foreach` loop. It is also a eslint rule: https://cn.eslint.org/docs/3.0.0/rules/no-await-in-loop which recommends to avoid this and has an example of another approach

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing it too. I come from C# background and it would have worked there so I was expecting it to work here as well :) I wrote it using Promise.all and it is working now.

Comment: @VishalAnand Possibly consider adding your solution as an answer. It could be useful if shared explicitly.

Comment: adding it now. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` to create an array of promises from your middlewares. This array of promises can ben handed to `Promise.all` which resolves when every single promise of the array has been resolved.

```
await Promise.all(route.middlewares.map((middleware: IMiddleware) => {
            console.log('begin run middleware');
            const promise = middleware.process(request, response);
            console.log('resolve run middleware');
            console.log(request.body);
            return promise
        });
```

Or even more compact:

```
runMiddlewares(...) {
  return Promise.all(
    route.middlewares.map((middleware: IMiddleware) => {
      return middleware.process(request, response))
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: just curious, how is this different than my answer? also, why is async required inside map function?

Comment: Actually it is pretty similar (from control flow perspective). IMHO my answer is easier to less code and easier to read. For instance, you don't need to create a promise for the Promise.all, and you don't have to await it, as you are returning a promise anyhow. Array.prototype.map is often encouraged instead of manually creating new arrays from loops / forEach

Answer (score 0):

So, following the recommendation ( https://cn.eslint.org/docs/3.0.0/rules/no-await-in-loop ), I wrote it as follows

```
private runMiddlewares(route: Route | ExceptionRoute, request: HttpRequest, response: HttpResponse): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const middlewarePromiseArry: any[] = [];
            route.middlewares.forEach((middleware: IMiddleware) => {
                console.log('begin run middleware');
                middlewarePromiseArry.push(middleware.process(request, response));
                // removed the use of await inside of forEach loop following this link: https://cn.eslint.org/docs/3.0.0/rules/no-await-in-loop
                // await middleware.process(request, response);
                // console.log('resolve run middleware');
                // console.log(request.body);
            });

            await Promise.all(middlewarePromiseArry);
            console.log('resolve all runMiddlewares');
            resolve();
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I am happy to accept further answers and recommendations/improvements :)